# Сортировка внутри JSON (sql, Postgres)

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

[image: example]

Есть таблица в Postgres, как на картинке. Формат данных в before и after - JSON.
Необходимо сравнить данные из before и after внутри zone_limitation. Основная проблема заключается в том, что данные могут иметь разную сортировку, а при разной сортировке такие JSON-ячейки будут восприниматься, как разные, даже если будут иметь одинаковые цифры внутри.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в postgresql есть операторы [@> и <@ для jsonb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)

эти операторы проверяют структурного вхождение одного jsonb в другой (не взирая на последовательность ключей), т.о. если вам нужно проверить эквивалентность, то можно использовать комбинацию этих операторов, например:

```
with t as (
  select 
    "id",
    "before"#>'{"custom_targeting","include","zone_limitation"}' as "b",
    "after"#>'{"custom_targeting","include","zone_limitation"}' as "a"
  from "test"
)
select 
  t.id "id",
  (t.a @> t.b and t.a <@ t.b)::boolean "Checker"
from t 
order by 1
```

*данный ответ базируется на dbfiddle от 2SRTVF, см. оригинальный ответ:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/858064/265453

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> create table "test" (
>   "id" int,
>   "before" jsonb,
>   "after" jsonb
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into "test" ("id","before","after") values
> (1,'{"custom_targeting":{"include":{"zone_limitation":["1","2"]}}}','{"custom_targeting":{"include":{"zone_limitation":["2","1"]}}}'),
> (2,'{"custom_targeting":{"include":{"zone_limitation":["1","3"]}}}','{"custom_targeting":{"include":{"zone_limitation":["1","5"]}}}');
> ```

> ```
> with t0 as
> (
>   select 
>     "id",
>     json_array_elements(("before"#>'{"custom_targeting","include","zone_limitation"}')::json)::text "lz"
>   from "test"
> ),
> t1 as (
>   select 
>     "id",
>     json_array_elements(("after"#>'{"custom_targeting","include","zone_limitation"}')::json)::text "lz"
>   from "test"
> )
> select 
>   case when t0."id" is null then t1."id" else t0."id" end "id",
>   (min(case when t0."id" is null or t1."id" is null then 0 else 1 end))::boolean "checher"
> from t0 
>  full join t1 on t0."id" = t1."id" and t0."lz" = t1."lz"
> group by 1
> order by 1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | checher
> -: | :------
>  1 | t      
>  2 | f
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=83bdf0db877642abb4be810e7c462462)*

Answer (score -1):

Не совсем понял, при чём тут сортировка. Вы пишете, что надо сравнить поля в пределах одной записи.  
Вообще говоря, такая таблица нарушает, насколько помню, даже первую нормальную форму — элементарность столбцов. Разумеется, никакой SQL-сервер с такими столбцами внятно работать не умеет.  
Можно, например, вынести из строк информацию, с которой вы намерены работать, в дополнительные столбцы. Например, коли уж вам нужен zone_limitation, сдублировать (либо вынести) в отдельные столбцы.  
Можно написать свой тип, написать к нему функций и операций.

Comment: postgres умеет: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-json.html